# sqlalchemy orm skip already-existing tables on create

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How can I avoid this exception in sqlalchemy orm when I try to create a table which already exists in a database:

> sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Table 'col1' is already defined for this MetaData instance.  Specify 'extend_existing=True' to redefine options and columns on an existing Table object.

```
Base = automap_base()
Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)

class Col1(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'col1'
    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String())

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Comment: This happens because you are *declaring* a table with the same name in the same `MetaData` instance, not because you are *creating* a table with the same name in the same database. There's a table with the same name in the same `MetaData` instance because you are reflecting tables from the database and there is a table with the same name in the database. Why are you declaring a new table if you've already reflected it from the database? If you just want an ORM class from it, perhaps [automap](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/automap.html) is of help.

Comment: I'm declaring a new table bcz I'm not sure if it exists or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I needed to add `{'useexisting': True}` (in SQLAlchemy 1.4+, use `{'extend_existing': True}`).

```
class Col1(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'col1'
    __table_args__ = {'useexisting': True}
    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String())
```

Comment: Where did you find the parameters that goes on `__table_args__`, I have read the table configuration documentation and I did not found nothing.